# how to solve this problem:permission error file path in cocoapods

Tags: file, permissions, rubygems

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/installer.rb:713:in `verify_gem_home' /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/installer.rb:903:in` pre_install_checks'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/installer.rb:303:in `install' /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/specification.rb:105:in` install'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:195:in `block in install' /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:183:in` each'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:183:in `install' /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:215:in` install_gem'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:231:in `block in install_gems' /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:224:in` each'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:224:in `install_gems' /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:170:in` execute'

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/installer.rb:713:in `verify_gem_home' /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/installer.rb:903:in` pre_install_checks'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/installer.rb:303:in `install' /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/specification.rb:105:in` install'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:195:in `block in install' /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:183:in` each'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:183:in `install' /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:215:in` install_gem'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:231:in `block in install_gems' /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:224:in` each'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:224:in `install_gems' /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:170:in` execute'
Permission error